# x3650 IBM ServeRAID 8k

Tags: raid, ibm

I have 6 disks into RAID5 array, I bought 2 new disks and I will add to the existing array. I try with IBM ServeRAID 8k utility but i can find the option for append disk into an array.

i have CentOS and launch the utility from the bios

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SR8k BIOS is quite limited. Array expansion can be done via RAID manager software
http://www-947.ibm.com/support/entry/portal/docdisplay?lndocid=MIGR-61707